GET doesnt retrieve the id from URL
I´m trying to capture the value of id by using the URL, but always while printing the array for debugging it's null.
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

     $user_id = isset($_GET['id']);

     echo '<pre>';    
     print_r($_GET);
     echo '</pre>';

    if ($conn === false) {
        die("Error");
    }

    if ($user_id === null) {
        echo "<script>
                Swal.fire({ 
                    title: 'Invalid Request', 
                    text: 'No user ID specified.', 
                    icon: 'error', 
                    button: 'Close' 
                }).then(function() {
                    window.location = '...';
                });
            </script>";
    } else {

I tried printing the get variable but doesnt show anything

How is the variable being passed? Are you doing so through query parameters (/my-url?id=1234) or via a form field? If it's via a form field - it may be coming through on $_POST instead (depending on how you have set it up.

Please check your post URL has the proper query string like find-user?id=234. for that in this page print request_uri echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
